# Autofac passing named parameters for types loaded using RegisterAssemblyTypes

Tags: c#, autofac

I am registering some types in Autofac using named parameters like this

```
 builder.Register<LogRequest>((c, p) =>
    {
        var param = p.Named<TenantConfigurations>("myparam");
        if (param is MyClass)
        {
            return new LogRequest(param as MyClass);
        }
        return null;
    });
```

How can i do the same for types that I register with `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes` method. Assuming that all types constructor takes same parameter `param`

**Update**

This is what i ended up doing

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(CustomType)
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(CustomType) && !t.IsAbstract)
                    .ToList().ForEach(t =>
                                        {
                                            builder.Register((c, p) =>
                                            {
                                                var param = p.Named<TenantConfigurations>("myparam");
                                                if (param is MyClass)
                                                {
                                                    return t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TenantConfigurations) }).Invoke(new object[] { config });
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do that using "WithParameter" extension. Example:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).WithParameter("param", "value");
```

**Update:**

Also, you can do that by using ["LifetimeEvents"](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/LifetimeEvents). Simple usage example:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).OnActivating(args =>
{
    var param = args.Parameters.Named<string>("param");
    args.ReplaceInstance(new HelloWorld(param));
});
```

Comment: The param value is not constant and is decided during resolving process, where the parent class get a parameter and it passes along.

Comment: @Chandermani Sorry, I did not see that in question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alexandr, i did something similar but did not use the OnActivating event

Comment: @Chandermani I posted just simple working example, you have to extend it to filter by instance type that you need to replace. Thanks.